# LD_LIBRARY_PATH for gtest_discover_tests (in QtCreator?)

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator, googletest

I have a CMAKE project which contains two subdirectories, library and tests.  When it comes time enumerate the tests, gtest_discover_tests runs the test executable but because the test executable is in a sibling directory to the library being tested it doesn't seem to find it.  If I run it by terminal and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH it runs fine.  Is there a CMAKE way to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the compilation process?  I can force it in my IDE but that's fragile for other people attempting to compile it.

foo/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(foo)

add_subdirectory(library)
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

foo/library/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(foo SHARED foo.cpp foo.h)
```

foo/tests/CMakeLists.txt

```
enable_testing()

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

include_directories(../library)

add_executable(foo_test foo_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo_test PRIVATE gtest_main foo)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(foo_test)
```

exact error output

```
[1/1 5.1/sec] Linking CXX executable tests/foo_test
FAILED: tests/foo_test tests/foo_test[1]_tests.cmake 
: && /usr/lib/ccache/clang++-11 --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --sysroot=/ -g  tests/CMakeFiles/foo_test.dir/foo_test.cpp.o -o tests/foo_test -L/home/adam/workspace-qt/foo/tests/../library -Wl,-rpath,home/adam/workspace-qt/foo/tests/../library:home/adam/workspace-qt/build-foo-Clang_Desktop-Debug/library  lib/libgtest_maind.a  library/libfoo.so  mbedtls/library/libmbedtls.a  lib/libgtestd.a  -lpthread  mbedtls/library/libmbedx509.a  mbedtls/library/libmbedcrypto.a && cd /home/adam/workspace-qt/build-foo-Clang_Desktop-Debug/tests && /home/adam/Qt/Tools/CMake/bin/cmake -D TEST_TARGET=foo_test -D TEST_EXECUTABLE=/home/adam/workspace-qt/build-foo-Clang_Desktop-Debug/tests/foo_test -D TEST_EXECUTOR= -D TEST_WORKING_DIR=/home/adam/workspace-qt/build-foo-Clang_Desktop-Debug/tests -D TEST_EXTRA_ARGS= -D TEST_PROPERTIES= -D TEST_PREFIX= -D TEST_SUFFIX= -D NO_PRETTY_TYPES=FALSE -D NO_PRETTY_VALUES=FALSE -D TEST_LIST=foo_test_TESTS -D CTEST_FILE=/home/adam/workspace-qt/build-foo-Clang_Desktop-Debug/tests/foo_test[1]_tests.cmake -D TEST_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT=5 -D TEST_XML_OUTPUT_DIR= -P /home/adam/Qt/Tools/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake
/home/adam/workspace-qt/build-foo-Clang_Desktop-Debug/tests/foo_test: error while loading shared libraries: libfoo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CMake Error at /home/adam/Qt/Tools/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:77 (message):
  Error running test executable.

    Path: '/home/adam/workspace-qt/build-foo-Clang_Desktop-Debug/tests/foo_test'
    Result: 127
    Output:
      

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/adam/Qt/Tools/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:173 (gtest_discover_tests_impl)


ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
15:56:10: The process "/home/adam/Qt/Tools/CMake/bin/cmake" exited with code 1.
Error while building/deploying project foo (kit: Clang-Desktop)
When executing step "Build"
15:56:10: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

**EDIT:**

Discussion with @Tsyvarev has illuminated that QtCreator may not be putting a fully qualified path in RPATH/RUNPATH. (ie 'home/...' instead of '/home/...').

Comment: When build executables and shared libraries, CMake normally tells the linker to embed to them **absolute path** to the linked libraries. Are you sure this is not your case?

Comment: It's not the linker's problem.  gtest_discover_test runs the linked executable to discover the tests as part of the cmake/compilation process.  At this point it's reporting it cannot find the shared library object.

Comment: Please, show (add to the question post) the **exact error message**.

Comment: I've added the error message per my system.

Comment: The option `--sysroot=/` looks weird. I guess that without it CMake would set the absolute library path instead of `home/adam/workspace-qt/foo/tests/../library`, which is "almost absolute". Do you use some specific **toolchain** for build your project?

Comment: I use the LLVM/Clang toolchain to compile my code.  QtCreator is my IDE of choice. 
 I think I just noticed a strange effect.  When compiled in QTCreator I have this issue.  If I compile it by hand it works perfectly.  The one compiled by hand has a full path in RUNPATH and the one compiled by QtCreator is missing that starting '/'.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue. The workaround for me is to add RPATH for the `foo` library in your case. Then there is no need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  for gtest. This can be done by setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` when installing the `foo` library. I similar post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66394189/19773052

Another workaround is from this post: [CMAKE Linking dynamic library to module, but not showing as link dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310631/cmake-linking-dynamic-library-to-module-but-not-showing-as-link-dependency). The more elegant way is `target_link_options(foo_test PRIVATE -Wl,--as-needed)`. But perhaps this will include unnecessary linking information to the executable.